# According to critics of the 1970 Missal of St Paul V, what specifically was good about it?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy

On https://www.newliturgicalmovement.org/2022/04/best-quotes-on-liturgy-by-joseph.html I saw that then-Cardinal Ratzinger said

> There is no doubt that this new missal [after Vatican II] in many respects brought with it a real **improvement and enrichment**

and

> Even the official new books, **which are excellent in many ways**, occasionally show far too many signs of being drawn up by academics and reinforce the notion that a liturgical book can be “made” like any other book.

Whereas he is still critical of the missal overall.

He does not specify what exactly was an 'improvement'. Do any critics of the new missal specify what they believe to be objectively good additions or changes?

Comment: My wife is finishing an MA in theology this year, and while she is critical of some of the changes, one thing she always highlights as good is that we read more Scripture now than we did before Vatican 2. For instance, we used to only have readings from Matthew all year, whereas now we read from all four Gospels.

Comment: @jaredad7 I had considered that, but it seems the majority opinion among serious critics is that the new lectionary is *worse* not better, such as what was written here: https://rorate-caeli.blogspot.com/2019/01/not-just-more-scripture-but-different.html

Comment: I do agree that the omission of "difficult" teachings is a problem. I sent that article to my wife to get her opinion on it.